# ios Translucent Navigation Bar causes view dislocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My project has a main view M embedded in navigation controller, implemented in storyboard/swift 3. M will push to a different view C which is implemented completely in object-C codes and does all its layout in the codes. When the Translucent property of M's navigation controller is checked, C looks correctly. However, if the Translucent property is un-checked, the whole view of C is lowered by exactly the high of the navigation bar.

In the screenshots below. The left is with translucent which has the round button visible fully. The right is without translucent and the button is lowered and partially covered. (The color looks slightly different due to the translucent setting difference.)

[image] [image] [image]

The codes that renders the view does not look remarkable. I walked through the codes in the debugger, the screen size and frame coordinates used are exactly the same in the two translucent mode.

```
// obj-c codes for C
@interface ViewControllerC : UIViewController{
// ...
}
@end

CGFloat w,h;
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
w = rect.size.width;
h = rect.size.height;
btnToolbar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((w-TOOLBARW)/2,h-80,TOOLBARW,80)];
btnToolbar.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
// buttons added into the btnToolbar

// ------------------------------------------
// Swift 3 code that instantiate and push C
if let vc = ViewControllerC()  {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

What happens? And how to fix?